# Is this PDE solution correct?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, initial-value-problems

Consider the following Heat Equation $$u_{xx} = \pi^2 u_t,\ u(0,\ t) = 10,\ u(3,\ t) = 22,\ u(x,\ 0) = 4x + 17$$

I want to solve this via separation of variables, which will require finding the steady-state solution, and the remainder of the solution.  Since both of these parts will want to utilize a lot of the same letters, I will use color to indicate namespaces while avoiding subscript hell, so I will have $u(x,\ t) = \color{#CE2029}{u(x,\ t)} + \color{#0048BA}{u(x)}$, where $\color{#0048BA}{u(x)}$ is the steady-state solution and $\color{#CE2029}{u(x,\ t)}$ is the remainder of the solution, and all constants, variables, and functions will similarly be colored blue if they are associated with the steady-state solution and red if they are associated with the remainder.

Starting with the steady-state solution, I have $\color{#0048BA}{u_{xx} = 0,\ u(0) = 10,\ u(3) = 22}$.  The general solution is $\color{#0048BA}{u = Ax + B}$, and plugging in the initial conditions I get that $\color{#0048BA}{A = 4}$ and $\color{#0048BA}{B = 10}$, yielding the particular solution $\color{#0048BA}{u = 4x + 10}$.

Subtracting this steady-state problem from the original problem, the remaining problem is $\color{#CE2029}{u_{xx} = \pi^2 u_t,\ u(0,\ t) = 0,\ u(3,\ t) = 0,\ u(x,\ 0) = 7}$.  Plugging in the separated form $\color{#CE2029}{u = X(x)T(t)}$ leads to the general solution $\color{#CE2029}{u = Ae^{\lambda t}(Be^{-\pi \sqrt\lambda x} + Ce^{\pi \sqrt\lambda x})}$.  If I absorb $\color{#CE2029}A$ into $\color{#CE2029}B$ and $\color{#CE2029}C$, then plug in the boundary conditions, I get $\color{#CE2029}{C = -B}$ and $\color{#CE2029}{\lambda = -\frac{n^2}{9}}$, and thus the solution $\color{#CE2029}{u = e^{-\frac{n^2 t}{9}}(Be^{-\frac{n\pi xi}{3}} - Be^{\frac{n\pi xi}{3}})}$.  Applying Euler's formula and lumping constants again yields $\color{#CE2029}{u = Be^{-\frac{n^2 t}{9}}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{3})}$.

Summing all of the solutions produces $\color{#CE2029}{u = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty Be^{-\frac{n^2 t}{9}}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{3})}$.  For the initial condition, the Fourier Series coefficient $\color{#CE2029}B$ is given by $\color{#CE2029}{B = \frac{2}{3}\int_0^3 7\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{3})\ dx}$, which comes out to $\color{#CE2029}{B = \frac{14(-1)^{n + 1} + 14}{n\pi}}$, yielding the particular solution $\color{#CE2029}{u = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(14(-1)^{n + 1} + 14)\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{3})}{n\pi e^{\frac{n^2 t}{9}}}}$.

The total solution is the sum of these two parts $$u(x,\ t) = \color{#0048BA}{4x + 10} + \color{#CE2029}{\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(14(-1)^{n + 1} + 14)\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{3})}{n\pi e^{\frac{n^2 t}{9}}}}$$

Is this solution/process correct?

Edit in response to comment:  My understanding is that one of the major themes of the Heat Equation is that it makes discontinuities between boundary conditions and initial conditions disappear instantly, and that the same solution process will work with or without such discontinuities.  My source was [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iewkw4fbrco&list=PLlXfTHzgMRUK56vbQgzCVM9vxjKxc8DCr&index=47).

Comment: On a completely unrelated note: One can also just name functions differently, instead of putting subscripts. For example $s(x)$ for steady state solution and $r(x,t)$ for remainder :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven True, but this started to get unnatural with all the $T$'s, $A$'s, $B$'s, etc., and seems to get even worse in more complicated separation of variables problems.

Comment: Well, one gets used it :) as to most things in life. In any case, enjoy your PDEs and have a nice weekend

Comment: Your boundary conditions seem rather inconsistent... You write $u(x,0) = 4x + 17$ which implies $u(0,0)=17$ and $u(3,0)=29$ But on the other side you fix temperature at $x=0$ to 10 and at $x=3$ to 22 ?

Comment: @Steph Yes, is that an issue?  My understanding (from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iewkw4fbrco&list=PLlXfTHzgMRUK56vbQgzCVM9vxjKxc8DCr&index=46 ) was that one of the major lessons of studying the Heat Equation is that it makes such discontinuities disappear instantly, and that you can use the same mathematical approach that works for problems where the boundary/initial condition intersections have no such discontinuities?

Comment: Ummh. Heat equation with two discontinuities ... Interesting , I didn't know about this beofre. I will have a look to the video to see how it can be handled.